# GA4 API - Extract more than 11 columns

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am trying to extract 10 years data. The code works and allows me to extract 100000 rows but restraints number of columns. I would like to extract at least for 1 year.

Can you please advise how to increment the column volumnes

```
body = {'reportRequests': [{'viewId': viewID,
                            'pageSize': 100000,
                            'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2010-12-27', 'endDate': '2023-01-30'}],
                             'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:pageViews'},],
                            'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:pagePath'}],
                            "pivots": [{"dimensions": [{"name": "ga:yearWeek"}],
                                        "metrics": [{'expression':'ga:pageViews'},],
                                        }]
                                                   }]}
```

I am expecting to extract 10 years data from Universal analytics as part of ga4 migration and store it in our local database.

I am able to extract 100k rows for web pages visited each year (requirement - 10 years historic data) and segment it based on page views 'YearWeek' but the columns are constrained by 11. I would like to increment it to 53.

Any help on this, is appreciated?

Comment: just run that for each subset and combine locally?!  presumably they don't want you to impose unnecessary load on their servers by accident.  [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) would presumably be able to easily handle that amount of data

Comment: Is there a way to increment the date range?. Or else, I will have to run manually for every metrics?

Comment: given your [tag:python] tag it's easy to write a loop that does that isn't it?!

Answer (score 1):

A [reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet)  request can have a max of 9 dimensions and 10 metrics.

You cant change that.

[image]

[image]